# How to parse the text from an attribute

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have a little issue I need to overcome...
I'm quite new for parsing an XML file in Python but I managed to do it, and to convert it in csv file. 
Everything works well, except one data I am not able to get.

here the xml code:

```
<Stat Type="matchday">1</Stat>
<Stat Type="season_name">Season 2017/2018</Stat>
<Stat Type="symid">FR_L1</Stat>
```

here my python code for the line :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import csv


file_name="C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/BYG/Angers-Bordeaux.xml"
full_file=os.path.abspath(os.path.join('BYG',file_name))

dom=ElementTree.parse(full_file)


MatchDay=dom.findall('SoccerDocument/Competition/Stat')
TeamData=dom.findall('SoccerDocument/MatchData/TeamData')

for m in MatchDay:
    Match=m.get('Type')
    Day=m.text
```

It works but I all of them when I only want "matchday" and "1", I don't know how to select only this data, I tried many way, but they all failed..

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code, the library you're using, etc.

Comment: Are you using `xml.etree.ElementTree`?

Comment: @JackFleeting I added more of my code

Comment: @AfikFriedberg yes

Comment: First, there is no `1` in your xml; second, `xml.etree` is not the best library to work on xpath with. You should consider other libraries such as lxml.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python) for this. Beautiful soup lets you parse HTML pages, but since HTML is also just a form of XML, it also works with your example.

1. Install Beautiful Soup with `pip install beautifulsoup4`
2. Change Your code to the following:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file_name="C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/BYG/Angers-Bordeaux.xml"
full_file_name=os.path.abspath(os.path.join('BYG',file_name))

#  Read contents of your file
with open(full_file_name) as f:
    raw_text = f.read()

#  Parse XML with beautiful soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_text, features="lxml")

# Find all Stat Elements
elements = soup.find_all("stat")

# Go through all elements and print them
for element in elements:
    element_type = element["type"]
    element_text = element.text
    print(element_type, element_text)
```

This produces the following output:

```
matchday 1
season_name Season 2017/2018
symid FR_L1
```

Now if you are only interested in the elements of type `matchday` you can get them as follows:

```py
# Only select elements with type 'matchday'
elements = soup.find_all("stat", {"type":"matchday"})

for element in elements:
    element_type = element["type"]
    element_text = element.text
    print(element_type, element_text)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
matchday 1
```

Hope this helps :)